# Elm obtain Html Never

Tags: html, effects, elm

I have a normal view function `view : Model -> Html Msg`.

Now I need to product from that view a `Html Never`, which just removes all the event handlers.

My first idea was to use `Html.map` with a function `Msg -> Never` but I don't know how to define it since `Never` has no values.

Is there a trick to make this work?

Comment: Casting `Html Msg` into `Html Never` opens up a window for having HTML Nodes with possibly broken event listeners, which is a bad idea(memory leak or unexpected behavior). You'll have to write a native function to checks node facts (event listeners) and remove them from JavaScript representation of virtual DOM nodes, so this actually "works" and removes all the `Msg` for the nodes. **TL;DR:** what you want is a dangerous idea and Elm does not allow that for a reason. Could you please share more details on what are the end-goals?

Comment: Thanks @halfzebra. I must admint I don't fully understand your comment... Anyway, I am trying to use https://github.com/rupertlssmith/elm-server-side-renderer to print a string containing the initial rendered version of my view; the library uses always `Html Never`. I wanted a way to convert my `Html Msg` into a `Html Never` so that it could be used there.

Comment: I assume you want to re-use some of the front-end code you have for server-side rendering. As far as I know, server-side rendering for Elm only exists as an experiment(for now). Having views with `Html Msg` signature on the server-side is a little strange because they are not supposed to emit any events.

Comment: You can implement a native helper for tricking Elm compiler, here's an example [Elm type anitation](https://github.com/frenchdonuts/elm-autocomplete/blob/88081b2a7bd6b9084358379d1b37050c01b8e11a/src/Autocomplete/Autocomplete.elm#L36) for a [native "hack"](https://github.com/frenchdonuts/elm-autocomplete/blob/88081b2a7bd6b9084358379d1b37050c01b8e11a/src/Native/Tricks.js) This kind of stuff is heavily discouraged, so do it at your own risk. PS: I would also advise to ask on the Slack channel.

Answer (score 2):

`Html Never` would be a view without any event handlers. If you want to map this view to the type `Html Msg` you can use `Html.map never`. The function `never` is defined in the core.Basics.

I'd actually recommend to instead use a generic type for your view without event handlers, such as `Html x` and then you don't have to do any mapping at all.